# How to set on UITextField keyboardType NamePhonePad starting by default with alternate keyboard view

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uikeyboardtype

I need to set on UITextField keyboard type similar to NamePhonePad. But by default keyboard opens on letter characters, and I would like to open on numbers as default and has letters as alternative view.

Is there a way to revert order of default and alternate view of keyboard of given type or should I create new keyboard. If so how can be this implemented. Maybe there are some pods that have such design numbers + letters as alternative view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII Capable numbepad to achieve your desired functionality [image: check image]